# Fermi coordinates

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Recently I came across the concept of *Fermi coordinates* about a geodesic, which I now know are a generalization of normal coordinates in a Riemannian manifold. Do you have a reference for this topic or could provide the definition for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The book Tubes by Alfred Gray is a good reference. If you don't have the book you have the definition in the following paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938382900052

Comment: Many years late, but John M Lee on Riemannian manifolds 2nd edition has a section on this topic.